# Node.js - JavaScript - HTML - XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cors

Node.js - Javascript - HTML - XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Basically i have 2 scripts posted below one node.js and 1 javascript/html

i am posting data to my node.js file but i recieve this error and cannot see the result of the nodes.js on my html page.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.109:8111/?name=nknk. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.2.109:8111' is therefore not allowed access
```

Here is my **Node.js** file:

```
    var url = require('url');
    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

    if (queryData.name) {
    var basevalue = queryData.name;
    var value = basevalue.split (":");
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    console.log(value[0]);
    console.log(value[1]);

    exec ("casperjs test.js " + value[0] + " " + value[1] + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

    response.end(stdout);

    });

    } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
    }
    });


    server.listen(1234);
```

here is my html/javascript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head><title>Welcome To ....</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
    return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        // something per item
        var data = {}; //your own data
     $.post("http://192.168.2.109:8111" + "?" + $.param({name: msg[i]}), data);

    }
    // the old code
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1>
<form>
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="show array" onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
</form>
<br>
<textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>
</body></html>
```

Can someone help me fix this so that i can get the result back to my html without this error

```
----edit
```

this is code i am trying i can still not see the response data from the node.js server
i need to see the response from the exec command that my node server runs i know this takes about 40 seconds to complete but i still do not see anything outputted to html

node.js

```
var url = require('url')
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

if (queryData.name) {
// user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
var basevalue = queryData.name;
var value = basevalue.split (":");

console.log(value[0]);
console.log(value[1]);

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec ("casperjs test.js " + value[0] + " " + value[1] + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

response.end('_stdout(\'{"content": "blablabla"}\')');

});

} else {
response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
}
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8999);
~
```

javascript html

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head><title>Welcome To ....</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
    return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        // something per item
     //   var data = {}; //your own data
    //$.post("http://192.168.2.109:8121" + "?" + $.param({name: msg[i]}), data);
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.2.109:8999' + '?' + $.param({name: msg[i]}),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "_stdout",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
    function doSomethingWithData(data) { $('#message').val(data.content); }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    handleError(data);
    }
    });     

    }
    // the old code
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1>
<form>
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="show array" onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
</form>
<br>
<textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your web application is not hosted on the same host as your nodejs server, thus, you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can use JSONP:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('request received');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('_stdout(\'{"content": "blablabla"}\')');
}).listen(1234);
```

And your call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.2.109:8111' + '?' + $.param({name: msg[i]}),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "_stdout",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        doSomethingWithData(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        handleError(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: this looks like how I want to do this I understand the ajax but how would I implement jsonp to my existing code

Comment: i know it sounds stupid but can you show aan example of what i would replace in my code please i am very new to node.js

Comment: okay finnaly sorted the code out how can I output the data onto my html page I know its sending the data bit I still cannot see anything on my html page

Comment: There is no stupid question:)
If you want to put the response in your html page then implement the function in my example like this: 
`function doSomethingWithData(data) { $('#message').val(data.content); }`

Comment: can u take a look at my edit and correct it for me please i just cannot get this working been trying for days with different methods lol

Comment: Since you are already writing header data, I would suggest you try nikis's solution below, if you are still having trouble. JSONP is a workaround to the security model, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is working WITH the security model. Either way, make sure you have your debug window open in the browser so you can see the status of the request. That will help you figure out if the request is not working at all, or if it is going through correctly but not being processed by your client side application.

Answer (score 2):

This is **Same Origin Policy** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Modify your response at the following way:

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
});
```

Comment: Caution: use of "*" here will allow access to your API from any compliant URL. This may be what you want, or it might not. 
Read the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing page for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Comment: @JBCP Yes, I agree it's not a best solution because of security, but the local server is used and it's the easiest way to make things work. After that a more secure solution (JSONP, CORS...) should be implemented.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I just wanted to point it out so people are aware.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is simple.Just require cors module inside the server script side.
    Due to **CORS**(Cross Origin Resource Sharing),which is disabled unless enabled otherwise in most of the modern browser.
    In node require cors module in the application and use it accordingly.

```
Ex:

var cors=require(‘cors’);
var app=express();
app.use(cors());
```